# Adverts in active wall paper

Tags: android, ads

Is it acceptable to put an admob advert in a live wallpaper? If not what ways can I use that at least once in a day the user will see an add? I want to maximise footfall to the adds without breaking any rules. Putting them in the settings seems a bit hit and miss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Potentially.

#### Annoying the users:

I'm pretty sure that doing that all the time would seriously piss off your users. I'd have the ads come on one every 10, or 5, but no less than 5, times, with a button to dismiss the ad.

#### Legal:

I'm not sure if there are any rules on not putting ads in sensitive locations, but I'm pretty sure that there are none.

#### Ad content:

I'd screen your ads for inappropriate content, and have a checkbox to allow certain types of ads. You could get a huge quantities of bad reviews. If a child's playing with a smartphone and they see an inappropriate ad, as tends to happen on the Internet, you'd probably get a quick 1-star review and an uninstall, not to mention missing out on further revenue from that consumer.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on the ad content. Yes I was thinking it would get on peoples nerves. Maybe I need to make it attractive to go and fiddle with the settings from time to time.